# Is Google Pay free?

Tags: online-payment, google

I'm planning to integrate Google Pay into a small website, and I've done some initial research that suggests it might be free. However, I want to confirm this with the community. Can anyone provide insights into whether Google Pay integration is indeed free for small websites, or are there any associated costs that I should be aware of? Additionally, if there are any specific considerations or steps I should follow for a small-scale implementation, I would greatly appreciate any advice or pointers. Thanks in advance for your help!